# Exit a method that contains an invoke command

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a method that runs some tasks in the background called **backgroundworker5_doWork()**. This method call the **Invoke** instruction which helps me to access the controls on my windows form (since a control cannot be accessed from another thread normally) as such

```
 private void backgroundWorker5_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!isAdmin)
        {             
            //Start of invoke instruction   
            Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                if(test)
                {
                    return;
                }

                if (ValidateAll())
                {
                    comboBox5.Items.Clear();
                    packageToSendList.Clear();
                    progressBar3.Visible = true;
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                }

            }));
            //End of invoke

            RunAfterInvokeMethod() //Instructions called after the invoke 
       }
   }
```

My issue is that when **true**, the **return** instruction exits the **invoke block** (rightfully so) and executes the **RunAfterInvokeMethod()** which is not what I want. What I want is to exit the **backgroundWorker5_doWork()** method after the return is called.

I understand that it only exits the invoke instruction but is it possible to make it exit the parent method as well ? Maybe using other instructions ?

Thanks !

Comment: What about surrounding `RunAfterInvokeMethod()` with `if(!test)` or some other flag you make?

Comment: I also don't see anyone mentioning `goto` statements. (usually bad practice but if it avoids 2 flags I would say its usable here.)

Comment: Just a sidenote: Is `Invoke` marshalling to the UI Thread? In that case: You might want to think about what part of this needs to run in the background, what _can_ run in the background and what actually does. And I'd recommend to look into @JonasH 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73119783/982149) which is basically suggesting to replace this with async/Task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `bool` to help you with that, something like

```
private void backgroundWorker5_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if(!isAdmin)
    {             
        //Start of invoke instruction   
        bool doThis = true;
        Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            if(test)
            {
                doThis = false;
                return;
            }

            if (ValidateAll())
            {
                comboBox5.Items.Clear();
                packageToSendList.Clear();
                progressBar3.Visible = true;
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            }

        }));
        //End of invoke
        if(doThis)
            RunAfterInvokeMethod(); //Instructions called after the invoke 
   }
 }
```

Comment: `test` is already bool why don't you use that?

Comment: @Alp That's an option as well, but I don't see where it's declared, and I don't like using things like that.

Comment: @alp It might be argued that `test` is a placeholder for something else, and it is also possible that it can change value. Using a separate variable will ensure it has the correct value.

Comment: Thank you ! I am  going to mark this as correct since it is the easiest solution and it does the job !

Comment: @ShortyBeast Thanks, even thought occasionally the easiest one is not the best one, including this case 

Comment: @aca Yeah I agree with that Haha

Answer (score 5):

You can return a value (in this case, `bool`) from an invoked delegate:

```
bool result = (bool) Invoke(new Func<bool>(() =>
{
    if(test)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (ValidateAll())
    {
        comboBox5.Items.Clear();
        packageToSendList.Clear();
        progressBar3.Visible = true;
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    }

   return true;
}));
//End of invoke

if (result)
{
    RunAfterInvokeMethod() //Instructions called after the invoke 
}
```

Comment: This is 200 IQ answer.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a difference between  your Func<bool> and Action that I use in the invoke instruction ?

Comment: @ShortyBeast it means that the invoke method returns bool. So the method is the flag.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by aca would be the simplest solution.

I would however argue for rewriting your method to use [async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await), since this makes it much easier to run code on a background thread while still updating the UI on the UI thread.

```
var result = await Task.Run(MyBackgroundWork);
UpdateMyUI(result); // continue on the UI thread once MyBackgroundWork has completed
```

If you want to do some more background work after updating the UI you can always do another `Task.Run` after updating the UI to schedule some more work to be run.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Can I run multiple background tasks simultaneously using async/await?

Comment: @Shorty Beast Just run multiple `Task.Run`. It really depend on what you want to do. `Task.Run` for task parallelism, `Parallel.For` for data parallelism, Timers for reoccurring background tasks. DataFlow for pipelines etc.

Comment: Oh wow didn't know about this ! I will take a further look into it. Thanks for your help !